# Why does the short circuit current increase when we connect a distributed generator?

Tags: current, generator, short-circuit

I read that the short circuit current increases when we connect a generator to the grid. Why? Is this true for any kind of generator? (PV, wind turbine, synchronous generators, etc.)

Comment: 2 parallel batteries have twice the short circuit current of one. Think about it.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, but batteries are static elements, synchronous generators are dynamic ones for example, I think that when there is a short circuit generators stop working because of the absence of the electric torque that becomes 0, so why there is instead a positive contribution of generators to short circuit current?

Comment: PV is DC so, you have contradicted yourself. You also said *any kind of generator*. Please fix up your question to reflect what you want to know.

Comment: @Andyaka what I want to know is why they contribute to short circuit current if they stop working or are tripped to protect them?

Comment: OK, so where did you read this. Let's get back to the basics of your question. Please supply a link to the source information.